# How can I pass value store in localstorage in header of services using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have two api one is for login and another is for logout, and on succcessfulll login I am getting the acesstoken and on the basis of acesstoken I have to logout by passing the that acesstoken in header.

So for logout what I did, I stored that acesstoken value in localstorage and pass in the header but I am getting error "**AccessToken is invalid.**"

Here is services.js:

```
angular.module('server', [])
.factory('api', function($http) {
    var token = localStorage.AccessToken;
    console.log(token);
    var server = "http://myapi-nethealth.azurewebsites.net";
        return {
            //Login
            login : function(formdata) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: server + '/Users/Login',
                    data: $.param(formdata),
                    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                });
            },
            logout : function() {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: server + '/Users/Me/Logout',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization' : 'token ' + token},

                    /*headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'token '  + token},*/
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(status));
                });
            }
        };

    });
```

//Controller.js..

```
ctrl.controller('logout', function($scope,  $window,  $state, api) {
    $scope.logout = function() {
        api.logout()
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.response = data;
                $state.go('home');
                })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.response = data;
            });
    }
});
ctrl.controller('search', function($scope, $state) {
                $scope.search = function() {
            $state.go('clinic-list');
          };

    });
ctrl.controller('clinicCtrl', function($scope, $state, $window, api) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.clinicCtrl = function() {
    /*$scope.loading = true;*/
        api.login($scope.formData)
            .success(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.response = data;
                if (data.hasOwnProperty('AccessToken') && data.AccessToken.length > 5) {
                    $state.go('home');
                    window.localStorage['AccessToken'] = angular.toJson(data.AccessToken);
                    var accessData = window.localStorage['AccessToken'];
                    console.log(accessData);
                    } else {

                        $state.go('login');
                    }
                /*$scope.loading = false;*/
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.response = data;
                $window.alert($scope.response.Message);
                console.log($scope.response.Message);
        });
    }

});
```

Please tell me how can I do this....

Comment: how do you save the AccessToken ?

Comment: window.localStorage['AccessToken'] = angular.toJson(data.AccessToken);, I saved by using this line of code...

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('server', []).factory('authInterceptor',function($q,$location) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if(localStorage.AccessToken) {
                config.headers.AccessToken = localStorage.AccessToken;
            }
            config.headers.requestResourse = $location.$$url;
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function(response) {               
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }
}).config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
    })..factory('api', function($http) {
var token = localStorage.AccessToken;
console.log(token);
var server = "http://myapi-nethealth.azurewebsites.net";
    return {
        //Login
        login : function(formdata) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: server + '/Users/Login',
                data: $.param(formdata),
                headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            });
        },...............
```

this will append the token to all the requests, after u getting the reponse, in the controller you can re set the token :)
customize according to your variables

Comment: How can I pass token in "header"...I am able to get the token value but I have to pass it in header......

Comment: do u need the token for only one request ?

Comment: yes because this token value is change every time on the login....to logout that login user who loffed in I have to use this token value in header which is return by login api.....I don't know how can I pass this token value in header, I tried but I am getting an error "AccessToken is invalid."...see my code I pass token in header....

Comment: can you please explain, I am new to angularJS and I am not able to understand your code....

Comment: it will automatically done by angular you can the the auth token by  `AccessToken` parameter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255203/angularjs-clientside-routing-and-token-authentication-with-webapi