# Whats the correct format to send an authorisation header in a http request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I want to make a one time request.
This is part of a function in a service:

```
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic --key--';

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: api,

    }).then(callback);
```

I've also tried:

```
  $http.get(api , 
        { headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic --key--'}})
  .then(callback);
```

This is for a bing search api http json request.

I always need to manually enter the key in a dialog whenever i execute a request. 
The callback process the data. 
How can i automate/fix this?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255203/angularjs-clientside-routing-and-token-authentication-with-webapi

Comment: I was asking about sending a request with a basic auth key and correction in the syntax, not creating a session with tokens.

Comment: The principle will be the same as in the question.